# How to render multiple ag-grid in single component using Angular 6

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I have multiple ag-grid in html page, I want get the specific row values of an ag-grid in component.

html

```
 <ag-grid-angular #agGrid1 style="width: 1250px; margin-left: 5px ; height:120px;background-color: #CFD8DC;"
    class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowsData1" [columnDefs]="cols" rowSelection="multiple"
    [enableCellChangeFlash]="true">
  </ag-grid-angular>

 <ag-grid-angular #agGrid2 style="width: 1250px; margin-left: 5px ; height:120px;background-color: #CFD8DC;"
    class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowsData2" [columnDefs]="cols2" rowSelection="multiple"
    [enableCellChangeFlash]="true">
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

component.ts

```
  @ViewChild('agGrid1', { static: true }) agGrid: AgGridAngular;
  @ViewChild('agGrid2', { static: true }) agGrid2: AgGridAngular;

  getRowsData() {

      this.selectedRows1 = this.agGrid.api.getSelectedRows();
      this.selectedRows2 = this.agGrid2.api.getSelectedRows();
     console.log( this.selectedRows1,  this.selectedRows2)

  }
```

Here I am trying to  get the values of both ag-grid rows, but I am getting:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined error.

Comment: Hi @Zameer, please checkout the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide of StackOverflow. At the current state - your question is going to be closed. Please insert the code you have tried, what is the expected result and what actually happened. If there is an error log - include it as well. Maybe add a reproducible link to http://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ag-grid multiple instances in the same page using single gridOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385643/ag-grid-multiple-instances-in-the-same-page-using-single-gridoptions)

Comment: No, it did not fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

Done Ag-Grid setUp

And I have tried with below code , Bind grid Proper way

In your HTML File

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [rowSelection]="rowSelection" (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
          (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>

<ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [rowSelection]="rowSelection" (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
          (gridReady)="onGridReady1($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

and In app.component.ts file

```
private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;
  private gridApi1;
  private gridColumnApi1;
  rowSelection = "single";
  columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "Make", field: "make" },
    { headerName: "Model", field: "model" },
    { headerName: "Price", field: "price" }
  ];
  rowData = [
    { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
    { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
    { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
  ];
  onSelectionChanged() {
    var selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
    var selectedRows1 = this.gridApi1.getSelectedRows();
    console.log(selectedRows);
    console.log(selectedRows1);
  }
  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
  }
  onGridReady1(params) {
    this.gridApi1 = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi1 = params.columnApi;
  }
```

I am a able to get both value of grid in `onSelectionChanged()` method

Here is the output screen

[image] 
Hope this will help you

let me know if you have any issue with above

thanks

Comment: Hi kushal, thanks for your reply, i will try and update you.

Comment: @Kushal: can we add n number of ag grid in one component.thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes @Prasad we cam add n no of grid in one component, you just have to create different gridOption for each grid.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. You just did a typo: replace `@ViewChild('agGrid'...` with `@ViewChild('agGrid1'...` since that's the name you put in the HTML template.